# How to return a table without knowing its structure in advance?

Tags: oracle, plsql

everyone I need to create a function in oracle that accepts a table name and return a collection the content of which is based the table that accepted.

I've been doing some search, many examples are of the form: first, define a table type; then, fill a table of that type and return it.

But I won't know the structure of the collection that need to be returned until the function is called, so I can not define a table type at the time of programming.

How can I make it? Thanks:-)

What I want to do is this:
Say, I have three tables--TABLE_A, TABLE_B, TABLE_C--each of which has different columns. Now I need to create a function func(table_name) that accept the table name(TABLE_A, TABLE_B, or TABLE_C) and return a collection the content of which is determined by the table name passed to the function. As the three tables have different columns, I can't create a type like "TColumnData " which you created. So, how should write the function?

Comment: Have you tried DBMS_SQL? Create a REF CURSOR and throw a SQL select string at it (eg 'SELECT * FROM '||<p_table_name> where p_table_name is TABLE_A, TABLE_B etc); Have a look at the doco here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_sql.htm

Comment: This sort of question makes me ask other questions, such as "what is calling this function you need to write?" and "is this really the best way to go about this?"

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use global temporary tables.

```
    create or replace 
    procedure test_procedure(table_name varchar2) as
    begin
      declare
        table_or_view_not_exist exception;
        pragma exception_init(table_or_view_not_exist, -942);

      begin    
        begin
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'truncate TABLE TEMP_TABLE';
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE TEMP_TABLE';
        exception when table_or_view_not_exist then
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Table TEMP_TABLE not found. skipping drop..');
        end;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
                        'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS 
                         SELECT * FROM ' || table_name || ' ';
      end;
    end test_procedure;
```

then run the procedure:

```
    execute test_procedure('TABLE_A');
```

once the procedure has completed execution, you can verify by:

```
    select * from temp_table;
```

Comment: creating and dropping tables in production is not a nice solution. Also: what if 2 requests come concurrently?